# NHibernate fluent HasMany mapping inserts NULL Foreign key

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an entity Company that has many Orders. I mapped these as following to each other:

Company

```
HasMany(x => x.Orders).KeyColumn("CompanyID").Cascade.All().Inverse();
```

Order

```
References(x => x.Company).Column("CompanyID")
```

However when i create a new order for the company and try to save it, I get a SQL error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CompanyID', table 'Orders'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

(this is the generated SQL statement: INSERT INTO Order (Name, CompanyID) VALUES (?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]])

Which is a logical error because indeed I set CompanyID to be not nullable.

However with the inverse I expected CompanyID to be filled with the proper ID but by the life of me, I can't get it to work. I tried removing the Inverse (the behavior didn't change at all), changed the cascade, set the reference to be not nullable.

I even made the column nullable in the table to humor NHibernate. But that left me with an orphaned Order as it *did* create the Order record but left the CompanyID NULL.

This is my testcode where i made the new order:

```
Company test = RepositoryBase<Company>.GetById(1);
test.Orders.Add(new Order("test"));
RepositoryBase<Company>.SaveWithTransaction(test);
```

Updates by the way went all fine.

Anyway, I'm hoping someone here sees what I did wrong in my mapping.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to set the company on the order

```
test.Orders.Add(new Order("test") { Company = test });
```

inverse only tells NH that order uses the reference to Company on the Order object to insert the Id.

Answer (score 2):

Add this first!!!

```
test.Orders.Add(new Order("test"){Company = test});
```

Comment: @Tushar I don't know! Don't remember.

Comment: O_O. That's why you should explain the code in answer. :)

Comment: @Tushar See above! `:P`

Comment: What's the actual reasoning here?