# Fluent NHibernate HasMany mapping inserts null in foreign key

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public Parent()
    {
        Phones = new List<Child>();
    }
}
public class Child
{
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and mappings:
**child**

```
 public ChildMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Number).Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.Parent).Nullable().LazyLoad().Cascade.None();
        }
```

and **parent**

```
public ParentMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Number).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Children).Inverse().Cascade.All();
    }
```

but when i insert children to parent, it goes with null in parent foreign key.

```
var p = rep.Get(g => g.Id == 1);
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(s => new Child()
    {
        Number = s.ToString()
    }).ToList().ForEach(p.Children.Add);
rep.Update(p);
rep.Flush();
```

actualy everything like in post [NHibernate fluent HasMany mapping inserts NULL Foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244609/nhibernate-fluent-hasmany-mapping-inserts-null-foreign-key)

But insert link like this `test.Orders.Add(new Order("test") { Company = test });` absolutly **not true** way, so i need help, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

```
public ParentMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Number).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Children).Cascade.All();
    }
```

**Without inverse**

Answer (score 1):

You have a bidirectional relationship set up between `Parent` and `Child`, but when you are adding a child to the `Children` collection on `Parent`, you are not setting the `Parent` property on each child.

The first thing I would recommend is question whether the relationship needs to be bidirectional - will typical usage work with Children independent of their Parents? Would you need to navigate the object graph in the direction from `Child` to `Parent`? Are both `Parent` and `Child` **[Aggregate Roots](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/16/ddd-aggregates-and-aggregate-roots.aspx)**?

There are a few different ways to handle bidirectional relationships. One way is to define Add and Remove methods that add a `Child` to the `Children` collection and sets the `Parent` property on each child and to remove the ability to add a child directly to the collection, by making it an `IEnumerable<Child>` (or `IReadOnlyCollection<Child>`, or similar) for example with an `IList<Child>` backing field

```
public class Parent
{
    private IList<Child> _children;

    public Parent()
    {
        _children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children { get { return _children; } }

    public virtual void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
        child.Parent = this;
    }

    public virtual void RemoveChild(Child child)
    {
        _children.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = null;
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The ParentMap should be modified to use the backing field

```
public ParentMap()
{
    Map(x => x.Number).Not.Nullable();
    HasMany(x => x.Children).Inverse()
                            .Cascade.All()
                            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
}
```

Comment: It seems nice to do the same for the Parent in Child class.

Comment: @mehdi.loa `Parent` *owns* the relationship, so it makes sense to set the properties when adding to the child collection on `Parent`.

Comment: @Roar what's not flexible?

Comment: @RussCam i dont want to add additional methods, i need mapping which will get parent item for each children

Comment: @Roar This is the general way to do bi-directional relationships with NHibernate. If the relationship doesn't *need* to be bi-directional, remove the `Parent` property from `Child` and use what you have already; a foreign key to `Parent` table will be created on the `Child` table for you.

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(s => new Child()
    {
        Number = s.ToString(),
        Parent = p
    }).ToList().ForEach(p.Children.Add);
```

Comment: But insert link like this test.Orders.Add(new Order("test") { Company = test }); absolutly not true way, so i need help, any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem with that?

Comment: accidentally, someone can add children with property parent not linked to p

Comment: instead of using List you can use ObservableCollection, and in the CollectionChanged event handler set the parent.